# Filtering or possibly a mapping operation using collections in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Looks like I am probably having a dumb moment here. I have got a collection that I am trying to filter on basis of couple of conditions. Here is the array:

```
$files =[
   [
     "customisation_id" => "2357323",
     "file_type" => 2,
     "url" => "transparent/76caa009d0c2aa32793a8f48ad395dcb_616351.png.png"
  ],
  [
     "customisation_id" => "2357323",
     "file_type" => 3,
     "url" => "nonTransparent/5ae5a3ec64a35ebcaa26e211244c24a4_826308.jpg.png"
  ],
  [
     "customisation_id" => "2357324",
     "file_type" => 2,
     "url" => "transparent/5ae5a3ec64a35ebcaa26e211244c24a4_826308.jpg.gif"
  ],
  [
     "customisation_id" => "2357324",
     "file_type" => 3,
     "url" => "nonTransparent/64dc36fc492a87cf96f1fd2346e60dd3_560667.jpg.png"
  ],
  [
      "customisation_id" => "2357350",
      "file_type" => 2,
      "url" => "transparent/64dc36fc492a87cf96f1fd2346e60dd3_560667.jpg.gif"
  ],
  [
      "customisation_id" => "2357355",
      "file_type" => 3,
      "url" => "transparent/64dc36fc492a87cf96f1fd2346e60dd3_560667.jpg.gif"
   ]
];
```

I would like to create a new array out of it which has a `file_type of 2` with no duplicate records with same `customisation_id`. However, if there isn't a repeating record in terms of `customer_id` then just add it to collection. **NOTE:** I am using arrays interchangeably with
collection as I am going to use collection for it. Ideally, I want a new array or collection with following structure:

```
$files =[
   [
     "customisation_id" => "2357323",
     "file_type" => 2,
     "url" => "transparent/76caa009d0c2aa32793a8f48ad395dcb_616351.png.png"
  ],
  [
     "customisation_id" => "2357324",
     "file_type" => 2,
     "url" => "transparent/5ae5a3ec64a35ebcaa26e211244c24a4_826308.jpg.gif"
  ],
  [
      "customisation_id" => "2357350",
      "file_type" => 2,
      "url" => "transparent/64dc36fc492a87cf96f1fd2346e60dd3_560667.jpg.gif"
  ],
  [
      "customisation_id" => "2357355",
      "file_type" => 3,
      "url" => "transparent/64dc36fc492a87cf96f1fd2346e60dd3_560667.jpg.gif"
   ]
];
```

I have already tried filter, map and reduce methods of collection which solves the first part of puzzle but then I get stuck with second condition.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```php
$newArray = collect($files)->unique('customisation_id')->values()->all();
```

You should also read about `intersect()` : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-intersect